# Intellij gradle kotlin project generate .class files in both java and kotlin directory

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle Kotlin project setup in Intellij,

The source directory is as follows:

```
src
  main
    kotlin
    resource
  test
    kotlin
    resource
```

When I run from command line `gradlew build`, the .class files are only generated under
`./build/classes/kotlin/main/com/`

But if I run build task from Intellij Gradle panel, it generated .class files under both

```
./build/classes/kotlin/main/com/
./build/classes/java/main/com/
```

It causes errors on further Gradle tasks.

Since Gradle command line gives me expected result, I am assuming this is an issue related to the Intellij setting/bug.

How can I tell Intellij only generate .class file under `./build/class/kotlin` folder?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1 (Ultimate Edition).

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: Even to create the project from scratch locally, I can't reproduce the problem. I guess it must be some glitch, closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

This must because of some temp issue specific to my local project setting, as I can't reproduce this problem by recreating the project locally from the scrach, closing this issue.

Please ignore this question.